# Excel Filter, Multiple criteria, one column, both criteria true

Tags: excel

I need to be able to filter the Type column twice and cannot figure out how to filter one column twice (two different conditions). I searched for the answer online but still cannot figure it out. I would appreciate some help on this.

I would like to filter once for: Beverages and then again for Milk.

As a workaround, I have been copying and pasting this column multiple times and then filtering each column once. Sample data is below. Thanks

Data Have

```
Type                        Salesperson     Sales
Beverages - Milk            Suyama          $5,122 
Beverages - Orange Juice    Davolio         $450 
Beverages - Orange Juice    Buchanan        $6,328 
Beverages - Milk            Davolio         $6,544
```

Comment: When you filter are you looking for the result sum of all beverages and then a second result sum for that of just milk? It is not clear from your question what you want you expected results to be

Comment: @JackWilliams  just want to see the rows for 'Beverages - Milk', not the other rows. I want to do it my filtering column a twice, once by 'Beverages' and once by 'Milk'. This is sample data, there is a lot of data in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel 2013

```
How to Use the Custom AutoFilter on an Excel Table
Turn on the Excel Filters.
Select the field that you want to use for your custom AutoFilter.
Describe the AutoFilter operation.
Describe the AutoFilter filtering criteria.
Click OK.
```

[Custom AutoFilter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uiJa.jpg)